# macOS cannot connect to OpenVPN using Shimo - Kext error

Tags: macos, vpn, kernel-extensions

I am trying to connect to a VPN network using a OpenVPN profile I have imported to Shimo, but it fails showing this message.

> Shimo could not load its tun/tap kernel extensions, which are required by the used VPN protocol. Maybe you have some other VPN software running, which uses similar kernel extensions?
>
> Could not load kernel extension with identifier: net.sf.tuntaposx.tun

- I had another vpn app installed which I removed using AppCleaner and restarted my laptop.
- The .ovpn file is correct for sure because it is used by another pc and it connects successfully.
- Shimo is connecting successfully to other VPN networks such as PPTP.
- I have also manually created another profile using username/password instead of the stored certifications to connect to that OpenVPN and the outcome is the same.

**Debugging**

- For debugging I run `kextstat | grep -e tun -e tap` before Shimo started and there are no results.
- I run it again after Shimo started, again no results.
- And I run it again after error message is shown and this is the result.

`194    0 0xffffff7f83db6000 0x7000     0x7000     net.sf.tuntaposx.tap (1.0) 3D2DEB8A-5419-3CFC-A44F-AE197B319324 <7 5 4 1>`

- After that I execute `sudo kextunload -b net.sf.tuntaposx.tap` and the kext is unloaded successfully.
- Then again when I try to connect the same error message is shown and the kext is loaded again.

*I am using:*

- Shimo 4.1.5.1
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

**Note**
I have found also some guides indicating that I should execute `sudo rm -fr /Library/Extensions/tap.kext` and `sudo rm -fr /Library/Extensions/tun.kext` and reinstall Shimo, but I fear this could cause more problems.

Any thoughts? (Thanks for your time)

### UPDATE

I have now installed [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net) and imported the same .ovpn file and it connects successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After contacting their support they responded with the following which solved the problem.

> When this happens open the System Preferences and go to the Security & Privacy settings panel.  On the General tab, at the bottom right corner, there should be a message, saying that the use of system software was blocked with an Allow button next to it. After clicking on allow, there should be a dialogue to allow the use of software signed by Fabian Jaeger. If you don't see such a message do this alternatively:
>
> 1. Go to this page: http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/download.xhtml and download the tun/tap kernel extensions
> 2. Install the package, you have to quit Shimo and other VPN clients you might be using before doing so
> 3. Go to this folder: /Library/Extensions
> 4. There locate the tun.kext and tap.kext file and copy them
> 5. Go to your Applications folder, find Shimo, right-click on it and select Show content package
> 6. Go to the folder Contents/Ressources/tuntap
> 7. Paste the previously copied files inside the tuntap folder and override the existing ones there
> 8. Reboot your Mac and try to connect again with Shimo

Comment: I've tried to do all these steps without any luck. I couldn't force macOS to show the information about the untrusted kernel extension on the general tab of Security & Privacy. Only Tunnelblick saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth. I had this issue on Mojave, and in the end, rebooting simply made it work without reinstalling tuntap.